# C++ "Bus error: 10" and working with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, bus-error

I'm doing a Data Structures exercise and I have been blocked since yesterday with a bus error, which I reckon is because I'm doing bad things with the memory. But I cannot figure out what exactly.

These are the requirements that I have established for the practice:

- able to add a product (any way will do) to the list
- able to retrieve the product in the list at the current position (next, prev, moveToStart, moveToEnd… there's cursor pointer, called "actual" here)
- any changes I do to the retrieved product should be updated in the data structure (ie. list::retrieve(*product), product->visits++)

This is the code that I have. Apologies about the var names, I have to do it in spanish and therefore names are in spanish.

```
class producto { // My product
public:
    string marca;
    double precio;
    int visitas;
    int compras;

    producto () {}
    producto (string M, double P, int V = 0, int C = 0) : marca(M), precio(P), visitas(V), compras(C) {}
};

class nodo {
public:
    producto valor; // value
    nodo *siguiente; // next
    nodo *anterior; // prev

    nodo (producto P, nodo *A = NULL, nodo *S = NULL) : valor(P), anterior(A), siguiente(S) {}
};

class lista { 
private: 
    nodo *inicio;
    nodo *final;
    nodo *actual;

public: 
    lista();
    bool esta_vacia(); // is empty?
    bool es_final(); // is the end?
    int insertar(producto p); // insert given p
    void moverPrincipio(); // "move to beginning"
    void siguiente(); // "next"
    void imprimir(); // "print"
    int leer(producto *p); // read, return 0 or 1 if successful, return product by ref
};

lista::lista() {
    this->inicio = NULL;
    this->final = NULL;
    this->actual = NULL;
}

bool lista::esta_vacia() {
    return (this->inicio == NULL);
}

bool lista::es_final() {
    return (this->actual == NULL);
}

void lista::moverPrincipio() {
    this->actual = this->inicio;
}

void lista::siguiente() {
    if(!this->es_final()) {
        this->actual = this->actual->siguiente;
    }
}

void lista::imprimir() {
    int i = 1;
    producto *p;
    this->moverPrincipio();

    while(!this->es_final()) {
        if(this->leer(p) == 0) {
            cout << i << ".- ##" << p->marca << "##, Views ##" << p->visitas << "##\n";
            p->visitas++;
            i++;
            this->siguiente();
        }
    }
}

int lista::leer(producto *p) {
    if(this->actual != NULL) {
        *p = this->actual->valor;

        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

int lista::insertar(producto p) {
    if(this->esta_vacia()) {
        nodo *tmp = new nodo(p);
        this->inicio = tmp;
        this->final = this->inicio;
    } else {
        nodo *tmp = new nodo(p, this->final);
        this->final->siguiente = tmp;
        this->final = tmp;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have removed unnecessary code. This is how I'm using it (and failing miserably):

```
lista *productos = new lista();

productos->insertar(producto("Shoes", 19.90));
productos->insertar(producto("Socks", 25.00));

// I should expect views = 0
productos->imprimir();

// But now, views = 1
productos->imprimir();
```

Upon execution, the only thing I get is "Bus error: 10" when doing imprimir ("print"), the first time. Insertion works without errors (but something could be wrong there too).

My idea is to hold the product inside the node, and give a reference to its location when returning it, so that any changes are reflected there too (for example, increase the view or purchase counter of a retrieved element, reflects the change when reading the list later).

I'd be extremely thankful if someone could point out the mistakes I'm doing here.

Thanks!!

**UPDATE** [Here's a compilable example](http://pastie.org/private/lpnhowywj7mxyzfa385kog).

Comment: Consider `main()` and some executable example that utilizes your code therein as *necessary* code. That said, in `lista::imprimir`, the code `if(this->leer(p) == 0)`, I ask you: What is the value of `p` in that invoke?

Comment: @WhozCraig: hmm. Good question. I just want the "leer" function to store the result in "p", so that I can use "p" afterwards. What's the best way to do this? I do it this way, as I also want to be able to have error codes, unix-style. But maybe it's not a good idea…

Comment: @WhozCraig: I have updated the post with a link to a sample program http://pastie.org/private/lpnhowywj7mxyzfa385kog

Comment: You're sending an uninitialized pointer. If the purpose of the function is to store a pointer value *back in the caller's code* then you need to pass the pointer either by reference or by address (pointer to pointer) and set it appropriately. if you want to *copy* the structure then then caller shouldn't be using a pointer at all, Rather it should be using a `producto x;` and sending it by-address: `if(this->leer(&x) == 0)` or by C++ reference.

Comment: @AdriánNavarro: "I just want the "leer" function to store the result in `p`" - but `p` doesn't point to anything when you call that function, so there's nowhere to store the result. You need to pass a pointer to an object (e.g. `producto p; leer(&p);`) if you want it to work that way. But then modifying it (`p->visitas++`) won't do anything useful, since it's modifying a copy. You want `leer` to return a reference or pointer to `actual->valor`, not copy it somewhere else.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: yes, I tried using `leer(&p)`, it worked but the updates were not reflected. How should I do it? Must I do it via return? Thanks!!!

Comment: @AdriánNavarro: Yes, return a pointer or reference to the object, rather than copying it to another object, if you want to be able to modify it.

Comment: @MikeSeymour IT WOOORKS!! http://pastie.org/private/qypgh81d2qxfoaabvosg9a Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass a pointer to `lista::leer` and you want to write a value to it. You will be writing in unallocated memory. Probably, what you wanted was a pointer to the `actual` element.

First of all, you need to modify the signature:

```
int lista::leer(producto **p);
```

note the double star, since we will be writing the pointer itself.

Then, you have to assign a *pointer* to `actual->valor` to it in `lista::leer`:

```
*p = &(this->actual->valor);
```

Finally, you have to pass a pointer to `p` in `lista::imprimir`:

```
 if(this->leer(&p) == 0) {
     // ...
 }
```

Alternatively, you might modify `lista::leer` to return a pointer and check if it is `nullptr`/`NULL`.

Comment: Very useful. I went for the last option, which is return a pointer and check whether it's null (if it fails). I appreciate you taking the time to explain both options carefully. Thank you a ton!